# Deleting my profile, Done with SE

Tags: discussion

The final straw for me was the latest antics surrounding the moderator elections, and being told off by SE staff.

I have put in for deletion of TWP, and am deleting the rest of my accounts.

We're not being paid to deal with this abuse, and I for one, am done.

Joe: you are the best.
Mister Positive;  Thanks for your excellent work.
Kilisi.  Keep up the good work.
Magisch: If anyone should be a mod here, it's you.
Motosubatsu: It's been fun.  Take care.

And to anyone I've forgotten, apologies.

Comment: Good luck. Never give up?

Comment: I am not so regular here. But I recognized you by Richard_U in your profile. I have read answers by you so many times and they have helped me personally. Sad to see you are leaving too. Good luck!

Comment: I was just feeling like you were notably absent...guess I know why now. Sad to hear! Any links by anyone to the "antics" being referred to?

Answer (score 10):

At this [user's request](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/53586126#53586126), we have **cancelled their account deletion** and instead suspended them for a period of 132 days to let them make a clean break with the site.

Should they change their mind they can respond to us or contact the Community Team to reverse the suspension or proceed with an account deletion.

---

Please note that this was done at moderator discretion as it's not a recommended use of the suspension system. Anyone who feels they need a break from this or any other site can look into alternatives as well such as blacklisting the site address or using other productivity tools.

Comment: Thanks for the note. I almost thought SE unfairly suspended his account, that's why he is quitting the site. Good to know, it was his request instead.

Comment: If his account is deleted, will the 47000 rep be withdrawn from all the people he voted for?

Comment: @ThomasWeller Most likely they will be transferred to the Community user and preserved, as per [this meta thread](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/126471/260382)

Answer (score 6):

Good luck and best wishes on your journey. If it's not fun any more, then absolutely go find something fun to do, life is too short my friend.

Answer (score 5):

Godspeed Richard.  You will be missed!

Thank you for your willingness to share about your personal life and struggles.  Our conversations helped me more than you will ever know.

Good luck sir!